# charge socket on a Fuel Cell car

Tags: charging, automotive-design

I was looking into Toyota Mirai and Huyndai Tuscon Fuel Cell cars and thought to myself wouldn't it be great if I can charge a car when there is not enough juice to make it to the nearest hydrogen station. Is it possible for fuel cell cars to have a charge socket for battery charging?

Comment: I guess what you're asking for is a "Plug-in Hybrid Fuel Cell" vehicle.  Current plug-in hybrids have a limited "battery only" range and are then supplemented with a small gas engine.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting concept but I believe they generate electricity as-needed from the fuel cell and there is not much storage in a battery system. Just enough to start the reaction and maintain current to the traction motor. The fuel is in the hydrogen not a large battery. You would have to add a battery pack to the vehicle and at that point you might as well have an EV.Happy Day!